# EF6 Aggregation on large data sets

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

There are two tables, Events and Octave:

```
+---------+-------+
| EventId | Time  |
+---------+-------+

+----------+---------+-----------+-------+
| OctaveId | EventId | Frequency | Value |
+----------+---------+-----------+-------+
```

On average there are 10 Octaves for each Event, and an Event is recorded every every 10 seconds, right now there are around 400k events and 4 million octaves.
I want to filter the events in a specific time range, aggregate them by hour and return for each the average of the Octaves that have the same Frequency. 
The EF6 LINQ code I'm using is:

```
_context.Events
      .Where(x => x.Time >= afterDate)
      .Where(x => x.Time <= beforeDate)
      .Select(x => new { year = x.Time.Year, month = x.Time.Month, day = x.Time.Day, hour = x.Time.Hour, data = x.Data })
      .GroupBy(x => new { year = x.year, month = x.month, day = x.day, hour = x.hour })
      .Where(x => x.Any())
      .Select(x => new
      {
         Time = DbFunctions.CreateDateTime(x.Key.year, x.Key.month, x.Key.day, x.Key.hour, 0, 0),
         Data = x.SelectMany(y => y.data).GroupBy(y => new { frequency = y.Frequency }).Select(y => new
         {
            frequency  = y.Key.frequency,
            value = Math.Round(y.Average(z => z.Value), 1),
         })

      })
        .OrderByDescending(m => m.Time)
        .Take(limit);
```

Which works, but only when the time span is very little (some hours). If it's increased to some days the query seems to run forever. 
Am I asking too much to SQL Server? Or is there a better way to run this query/structure my data?
If I remove the SelectMany(...).GroupBy(...) then it's not crazy slow anymore.

The SQL query generated is:

```
SELECT 
    [Project5].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [Project5].[C2] AS [C2], 
    [Project5].[C3] AS [C3], 
    [Project5].[C4] AS [C4], 
    [Project5].[C5] AS [C5], 
    [Project5].[C6] AS [C6], 
    [Project5].[C8] AS [C7], 
    [Project5].[Frequency] AS [Frequency], 
    [Project5].[C7] AS [C8]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Limit1].[C1] AS [C1], 
        [Limit1].[C2] AS [C2], 
        [Limit1].[C3] AS [C3], 
        [Limit1].[C4] AS [C4], 
        [Limit1].[C5] AS [C5], 
        [Limit1].[C6] AS [C6], 
        CASE WHEN ([GroupBy1].[K1] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS float) ELSE ROUND([GroupBy1].[A1], 1) END AS [C7], 
        [GroupBy1].[K1] AS [Frequency], 
        CASE WHEN ([GroupBy1].[K1] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C8]
        FROM   (SELECT TOP (10000) [Project4].[C1] AS [C1], [Project4].[C2] AS [C2], [Project4].[C3] AS [C3], [Project4].[C4] AS [C4], [Project4].[C5] AS [C5], [Project4].[C6] AS [C6]
            FROM ( SELECT 
                [Project2].[C1] AS [C1], 
                [Project2].[C2] AS [C2], 
                [Project2].[C3] AS [C3], 
                [Project2].[C4] AS [C4], 
                1 AS [C5], 
                convert (datetime2,right('000' + convert(varchar(255), [Project2].[C1]), 4) + '-' + convert(varchar(255), [Project2].[C2]) + '-' + convert(varchar(255), [Project2].[C3]) + ' ' + convert(varchar(255), [Project2].[C4]) + ':' + convert(varchar(255), 0) + ':' + str(cast(0 as float(53)), 10, 7), 121) AS [C6]
                FROM ( SELECT 
                    [Distinct1].[C1] AS [C1], 
                    [Distinct1].[C2] AS [C2], 
                    [Distinct1].[C3] AS [C3], 
                    [Distinct1].[C4] AS [C4]
                    FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT 
                        DATEPART (year, [Extent1].[TimeEnd]) AS [C1], 
                        DATEPART (month, [Extent1].[TimeEnd]) AS [C2], 
                        DATEPART (day, [Extent1].[TimeEnd]) AS [C3], 
                        DATEPART (hour, [Extent1].[TimeEnd]) AS [C4]
                        FROM [dbo].[Events] AS [Extent1]
                        WHERE ([Extent1].[TimeEnd] >= @p__linq__1) AND ([Extent1].[TimeEnd] <= @p__linq__2)
                    )  AS [Distinct1]
                )  AS [Project2]
                WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 
                    1 AS [C1]
                    FROM [dbo].[Events] AS [Extent2]
                    WHERE ([Extent2].[TimeEnd] >= @p__linq__1) AND ([Extent2].[TimeEnd] <= @p__linq__2) AND (([Project2].[C1] = (DATEPART (year, [Extent2].[TimeEnd]))) OR (([Project2].[C1] IS NULL) AND (DATEPART (year, [Extent2].[TimeEnd]) IS NULL))) AND (([Project2].[C2] = (DATEPART (month, [Extent2].[TimeEnd]))) OR (([Project2].[C2] IS NULL) AND (DATEPART (month, [Extent2].[TimeEnd]) IS NULL))) AND (([Project2].[C3] = (DATEPART (day, [Extent2].[TimeEnd]))) OR (([Project2].[C3] IS NULL) AND (DATEPART (day, [Extent2].[TimeEnd]) IS NULL))) AND (([Project2].[C4] = (DATEPART (hour, [Extent2].[TimeEnd]))) OR (([Project2].[C4] IS NULL) AND (DATEPART (hour, [Extent2].[TimeEnd]) IS NULL)))
                )
            )  AS [Project4]
            ORDER BY [Project4].[C6] DESC ) AS [Limit1]
        OUTER APPLY  (SELECT 
            [Extent4].[Frequency] AS [K1], 
            AVG([Extent4].[Value]) AS [A1]
            FROM  [dbo].[Events] AS [Extent3]
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[Octaves] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent3].[EventId] = [Extent4].[EventId]
            WHERE ([Extent3].[TimeEnd] >= @p__linq__1) AND ([Extent3].[TimeEnd] <= @p__linq__2) AND (([Limit1].[C1] = (DATEPART (year, [Extent3].[TimeEnd]))) OR (([Limit1].[C1] IS NULL) AND (DATEPART (year, [Extent3].[TimeEnd]) IS NULL))) AND (([Limit1].[C2] = (DATEPART (month, [Extent3].[TimeEnd]))) OR (([Limit1].[C2] IS NULL) AND (DATEPART (month, [Extent3].[TimeEnd]) IS NULL))) AND (([Limit1].[C3] = (DATEPART (day, [Extent3].[TimeEnd]))) OR (([Limit1].[C3] IS NULL) AND (DATEPART (day, [Extent3].[TimeEnd]) IS NULL))) AND (([Limit1].[C4] = (DATEPART (hour, [Extent3].[TimeEnd]))) OR (([Limit1].[C4] IS NULL) AND (DATEPART (hour, [Extent3].[TimeEnd]) IS NULL)))
            GROUP BY [Extent4].[Frequency] ) AS [GroupBy1]
    )  AS [Project5]
    ORDER BY [Project5].[C6] DESC, [Project5].[C1] ASC, [Project5].[C2] ASC, [Project5].[C3] ASC, [Project5].[C4] ASC, [Project5].[C8] ASC
```

**UPDATE 1**

I've tried to 'flip' the query, by querying the octaves directly and I'm having better results. I first group them by date and frequency, calculate the average, then I group them again just by time. It's not elegant at all, but it's the first solution to actually work. If the grouping is done differently (eg first by time, then by frequency, then averaged) it still won't work.

```
 _context.Octaves
.Where(x => x.Event.Time >= afterDate)
.Where(x => x.Event.Time <= beforeDate)
.GroupBy(x => new { year = x.Event.Time.Year, month = x.Event.Time.Month, day = x.Event.Time.Day, hour = x.Event.Time.Hour, freq = x.Frequency })
.Select(x => new
{
  year = x.Key.year,
  month = x.Key.month,
  day = x.Key.day,
  hour = x.Key.hour,
  freq = x.Key.freq,
  value = Math.Round(x.Average(y => y.Value), 1)

})
.GroupBy(x => new { year = x.year, month = x.month, day = x.day, hour = x.hour })
.Select(x => new
{
  timeEnd = DbFunctions.CreateDateTime(x.Key.year, x.Key.month, x.Key.day, x.Key.hour, 0, 0),
  data = x.Select(y=> new {freq = y.freq, value = y.value })

})
.OrderByDescending(m => m.timeEnd)
.Take(limit)
```

Comment: Are there proper indexes in place? Have you thought about storing aggregated data per hour in a separate table? Would it be an option?

Comment: There are non-clustered indices on Events.EventId, Octaves.EventId, Octaves.OctaveId and Octaves.Frequency.
I have thought of storing aggregate data on another table, but hoped it wasn't necessary.
Thanks

Comment: Try creating a computed column on your table that represents the date+hour, then index that column.  Group by that column in your EF query and it should be a lot faster.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but you might want to try this. it might be worse i am not sure.

```
_context.Events.AsNoTracking()
  .Where(x => x.Time >= afterDate &&  x.Time <= beforeDate)
.GroupBy(x => new { year = x.year, month = x.month, day = x.day, hour = x.hour })
.Select(x => new
               {Time = DbFunctions.CreateDateTime(x.Key.year, x.Key.month, x.Key.day, x.Key.hour, 0, 0),
                   Data = x.SelectMany
                   (y => 
                        y.Select(h => 
                        h.data.GroupBy(y => y.Frequency).select(y => 
                                new {
                                        frequency = y.Key,
                                        value = Math.Round(y.Average(z => z.Value), 1)
                                    }
 ))))
    .OrderByDescending(m => m.Time)
    .Take(limit);
```